# Generating these p-values in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I need to compare two categorical tests as follows:

- A size $\alpha$ Pearson's test rejects $H_0$ if $Q(x) = {(x_1 - np_{01})^2 \over np_{01}(1 - p_{01})} > F_1^{-1}(1 - \alpha)$
- A size $\alpha$ binomial ML test. Rejects $H_0$ if $T(x) = {(x_1 - np_{01})^2 \over n(x_1/n)(1 - x_1/n)} > F_1^{-1}(1-  \alpha)$

Fix $n = 500$ and $p_0 = (0.4, 0.6)$. Generate an $x$ from
Multinomial$(n, p_0)$ (it suffices to get $x_1$ from  Binomial$(n, p_{01})$ and set $x_2 =(n -x1)$. Calculate the two p-values for this data under the two kinds of
tests. Now repeat this 100 times. Make a plot of these 100 pairs of p-
values and compare them with the 45 degree line. Are the two types of tests
behaving similarly for this simulation setting?

---

Using the following code, I am getting nonsensical answers. I'm not quite sure how I should plot these p-values either? Should I plot them $(p_B, p_M)$ as a pair?

```
# Lab 10
n = 500
p0 = c(0.4, 0.6)
x.1 = rbinom(1, n, p0[1])
x.2 = n - x.1
x = c(x.1, x.2)
Xtest = chisq.test(x, p = p0)
print(Xtest)
# Chi-squared test for given probabilities

# data:  x 
# X-squared = 0.0083, df = 1, p-value = 0.9273

## 100 times for X test
n = 500
p0 = c(0.4, 0.6)
x.1 = rbinom(100, n, p0[1])
x.2 = n - x.1
data = c(x.1, x.2)
x.mat = matrix(data, ncol = 2)
pvals.Q = 0
Q.x = 0
for (i in 1:length(x.1)){
Q.x[i] = (x.1[i] - n*p0[1])^2/(n*p0[1]*p0[2])
pvals.Q = 1 - pgamma(Q.x, 1/2, 1/2)
}
# for (i in 1:length(x.1)){
    # x = c(x.mat[i, 1], x.mat[i, 2])
    # pvals.Q[i] = chisq.test(x, p = p0)$p.value
# }

## Binomial Test
n = 500

x.1 = rbinom(100, n, p0[1])
x.2 = n - x.1
x = c(x.1, x.2)
p0 = c(0.4, 0.6)
T.x = 0
for (i in 1:length(x.1)){
    T.x[i] = (x.1[i] - n*p0[1])^2/(x.1[i] * (1 - x.1[i]/n))
}
pvals.ML = 1 - pgamma(T.x, 1/2, 1/2)

plot(pvals.Q, pvals.ML, ann = FALSE, type = "p")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first "set.seed" this will make sure that you are comparing the same datasets. As you have it coded you are comparing different random draws to each other. The rest of your code looks fine, though is often redundant (more typing than necessary!).

```
set.seed(123)
```

You can also get a straight line on your plot by using

```
abline(0,1)
```